# Finding real values of parameter t for which x has solution using plots in R

Tags: r, plot, equation

The problem in question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxmbh.jpg

The equation in question : x^2+4sqrt(tx)+t^2=0

I solved the equation by hand and I know that t=0 and x=0 the only problem is that I dont know how to plot that equation in R as it has 2 unknowns.

curve(x^2+4*sqrt(x*y)+y^2) but that didnt work.

Comment: This does not answer your question, but I read the equation in the post that you linked to as `x^2+4sqrt(t)*x+t^2=0`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a raster plot to make it clear that the function only increases away from zero. You could also have both t and x be negative, though it would be symmetrical on that side as well.

```r
foo <- function(x, t) x ^ 2 + 4 * sqrt(t * x) +  t ^ 2
df <- data.frame(
  x = rep(seq(0, 40, by = 1), times = 41),
  t = rep(seq(0, 40, by = 1), each = 41)
)
df$z <- foo(df$x, df$t)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) +
  geom_raster(aes(x = x, y = t, fill = z)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c()
```

[image]